# Svelte layout reset

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to reset the navbar and forward an active link to it. I read the advanced routing, and I think it's supposed to work like this.

```
src/routes/
│ test/
│ ├ **+page@test.svelte** //The whole point is to add@tags to svelte files for resetting
│ └ +layout.svelte
│
├ +page.svelte
└ +layout.svelte
```

The expected output is only one navbar with an active link working. Instead, I get 2 navbars, with the lower one doing what I want.

I'm following this guy from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7UlyE2Jhx4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hpM9ARM59Ve3jqcb54dqiP&index=8) .From 5:00 to 5:18, he gets 2 different navbars, which is what I want.

Comment: [The whole point of adding @ tags is to reset to a specific layout.](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts-page) Your `@test` makes no difference in this case as `test/+page.svelte` would already be using `test/+layout.svelte`.
If you want `test/+page.svelte` to have a blank layout then the root layout needs to be [empty and your other routes split into a group](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts-breaking-out-of-layouts).

Comment: Ahh, I figured out what resetting really means. I thought it would make it use just the specific layout from test and then downwards on. I see what you mean, it will still inherit from the top. Thanks!